# Mock an internal object call in a Flask view - with pytest

Tags: flask, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

Based on the following example:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/users')
def get_users():
    return UsersAPI().get_users()
```

And the following tests (using `pytest` and `pytest-mock`):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def users():
    return UsersAPI(how_many=1)


def test_simple(users, mocker):
    mocker.patch("???", return_value=users)
```

I simply want to call `UsersAPI(how_many=1)` instead of `UsersAPI()`. Is this possible to do?

(if you know how to get done with `unittest.mock` that is also fine since `pytest-mock` is simply some `pytest` wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is as easy as:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def users():
    return UsersAPI(how_many=1)


def test_simple(users, mocker):
    mocker.patch("path.to.module.UsersAPI", return_value=users)
```

And this also works:

```py
mocker.patch.object(path.to.module, 'UsersAPI', return_value=users)
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that this is the correct answer after a night of sleep... shouldn't write answers while sleep-depreviated.